# How do I set a final field via a setter?

Tags: java, class-design, final

I have the following abbreviated class:

```
public class Employee {

    private final float pointPosition;

    public Employee(float pointPosition) {
        this.pointPosition = pointPosition;
    }

}
```

I'd like to do checks on the `pointPosition` being passed in by the constuctor, to ensure that it doesn't exceed 1.0.

I tried moving the assignment to it's own private setter method that does a precondition check, but obviously that gave me an error since I'm reassigning a `final` field outside of the constructor.

I could change the constructor to something like:

```
public Employee(float newPointPosition) {
    verifyPointPosition(newPointPosition); //Will throw
    this.pointPosition = pointPosition;
}
```

But I'd prefer to have it all wrapped up neatly in it's own method.

What are my options here?

Comment: Have the verify method just return the input. I do this all the time in C++ for const members

Comment: @Bwmat Consider turning your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Don't make it final**

You could just not make it final and make the setter private.

---

**Option 2: Do the check and set in the Constructor**

That's what you already showed.

---

**Option 3: The hackish way**

You can set final variables with reflection, however i would definitely not recommend this unless you're forced to.

---

I'd go with Option 2. <s>If you're worried that your constructor gets too messy, you can just create additional constructors and set them private, for example:</s>

```
public class MyClass {
    private final float variable;

    public MyClass(float variable) {
        this();
        if(variable < 0.0f || 1.0f < variable)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'variable' has to be between 0.0 and 1.0");
        this.variable = variable;
    }

    private MyClass() {
        //Set everything else
    }
}
```

**Actually, this Code will not compile.**

Comment: Please please no-one ever do #3!

Comment: @tkausl Your example for Option 2 is actually Option 1 – `variable` is no longer `final`, otherwise `MyClass()` would not compile.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend doing this by just wrapping the argument passage in a single method call from the constructor.

You haven't said what behavior you want, whether to throw an exception if the value is invalid, or whether to just sanitize it to a normal value, but either way this will work:

```
public class Employee
  private static final float MAX_POSITION = 1.0f;
  private final float pointPosition;

  public Employee(float pointPosition) {
    this.pointPosition = sanitizePointPosition(pointPosition);
  }
```

And then you have two options:

1. Throw an exception:

   ```
   private float sanitizePointPosition(float pointPosition) {
     if(pointPosition > MAX_POSITION) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Point position must be <= "
                  + MAX_POSITION + ", it was: " + pointPosition);
     }
     return pointPosition;
   }
   ```
2. Set the value to something normal

   ```
   private float sanitizePointPosition(float pointPosition) {
     return pointPosition > MAX_POSITION ? MAX_POSITION : pointPosition;
   }
   ```